# DC motor +Raspberry pi3+ROS

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I want to control simple dc motors using R-pi3 and Ros,
Is it possible?
Not enough tutorials are available!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252581/dc-motor-+raspberry-pi3+ros/) by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9457 is also a nice motor drive an there is Raspberry Robot wich use it

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0